# What is "calling init:" in LD_DEBUG output?

Tags: c++, ld

Im working on c++,
I used LD_DEBUG environmental variable to  get library loading sequence as follows:

```
export LD_DEBUG=libs
```

and then executed the program. Following is the snippet of output.

```
|       3652:   find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
|       3652:    search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
|       3652:     trying file=/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
|       3652:   
|       3652:   
|       3652:   calling init: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
|       3652:   calling init: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/mySo.so.1
```

any one tell me the, what is the meaning of "calling init" in the above output statments?

Answer (score 1):

`calling init` means that any initialization functions (e.g. `__attribute__((constructor))`, static initializers, and other setup functions) are being called in that library.

Comment: Thanks , but How any initialization functions are being called, where as the library in which that function is not loaded till this point?

Comment: @BSalunke: You aren't seeing everything. The library is loaded between the `trying` and `calling`. Try `LD_DEBUG=all`.

Comment: Does that mean only "find library=" tag does not mean that library is loaded ? can you please tell me the how to know which libraries are loaded and in which sequence?

Comment: Use `LD_DEBUG=all`. You are not seeing all of the debug output.